# Accessing iCloud passwords without a Mac

Tags: ios, icloud, security, password, keychain

I mostly use Macs and iOS devices, so I've started using the iCloud password manager for better account security. Of course, all the world is not a Mac, but passwords are ubiquitous.

When I am using a Mac under my control I can use the Keychain Access app to look up my single-site passwords, but sometimes I'm on someone else's computer, which is usually not a Mac, and sometimes I use a Linux device, and so on. Even with iOS apps, sometimes I need to use my website password to log in using the app, and most apps don't seem to support iCloud passwords (although a few thankfully do!).

I do always have an iOS device with me, so are there any applications for iOS that allow you to access the iCloud Keychain to retrieve the plaintext password, like OSX's Keychain Access? Or is there a way to access the Keychain via the web?

Obviously the most Apple approach would be for me to always have a MacBook Air with me, but that also isn't feasible...

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085 and http://www.imore.com/how-access-icloud-keychain-passwords-credit-cards

Comment: For what it's worth, you could consider [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword). For about $75, you would have *all* your passwords with you all the time in a nice, easy-to-use package.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Yeah I've been considering that, and I think I actually have a license for it that I've never used (from MacHeist) but I'd like to avoid having to migrate a bunch of passwords over yet again :)

Comment: I have to say that after you're there, there is no looking back (at least that was the case for me). I have ~460 items in there.

Comment: @Buscar웃 That second link is useful and I hadn't found that myself. Thanks! Care to flesh that out and post that as an answer?

Comment: glad to be of help :) answer coming...

Comment: @bassplayer7 You're so right. I ended up trying out 1password and now I'm just like, wow, why didn't I start using this years ago?

Comment: I use many, many times every day. I would be lost without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to manually view saved passwords with iCloud Keychain

1. Launch the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad.
2. Scroll down and tap Passwords
3. Enter your phone password or scan your Face ID / Touch ID
4. In this list, find the login you'd like to view the password for and tap on it.
5. Here you can see the login credentials for that specific account.

Credit card information is saved in Settings > Safari > Autofill > Saved Credit Cards.

Source: [How to find saved passwords on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211146)